# Python interaction between two numpy arrays of the same shape involving cell neighbours

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, neighbours

I have two 2d bitewise arrays (1s and 0s only). I am doing

```
array2 = numpy.where( array1, 0, array2 )
```

which changes the values of `array2` when `array1` matches the condition. But what if I don't want to change the values of the very cells where the condition if satisfied, but their neighbors cells? I mean, instead of `i,j` for which `array1` evals to `True`, I want to change
the subarray `array2[i-1:i+2,j-1:j+2]`.
It is possible to avoid looping, which is really slow on big arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see [`scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html#scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter)

so in your example, the `footprint` argument would be `(3, 3)`, that is a neighborhood of 3 by 3 and the the `function` argument should return if the condition is true or false;

something like:

```
func = lambda xs: np.any(xs)  # or whatever appropriate
mask = generic_filter(array1, func, footprint=(3, 3))
array2[mask] = 0
```